# Can anyone help convert this VB Webservice?

Tags: c#, vb.net, web-services

I can't figure it out for the life of me.. I'm using SQL DataSet Query to iterate to a Class Object which acts as a Data Model for Flex... Initially I used VB.net but now need to convert to C#.. This conversion is done except for the last section where I create a DataRow arow and then try to add the DataSet Values to the Class (Results Class)... I get an error message..

'VTResults.Results.Ticker' is inaccessible due to its protection level
(this is down at the bottom)

```
 using System;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Web.Services;
 using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
 using System.Configuration;
 /// <summary>
 /// Summary description for VTResults
 /// </summary>
 [WebService(Namespace = "http://velocitytrading.net/ResultsVT.aspx")]
 [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
 public class VTResults : System.Web.Services.WebService {
     public class Results {
         string Ticker;
         string BuyDate;
         decimal Buy;
         string SellDate;
         decimal Sell;
         string Profit;
         decimal Period;
     }
     [WebMethod]
     public Results[] GetResults() {
         string conn =                
 ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection myconn = new SqlConnection(conn);
    SqlCommand mycomm = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter myda = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataSet myds = new DataSet();

    mycomm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    mycomm.Connection = myconn;
    mycomm.CommandText = "dbo.Results";

    myconn.Open();
    myda.SelectCommand = mycomm;
    myda.Fill(myds);
    myconn.Close();
    myconn.Dispose();

    int i = 0;

    Results[] dts = new Results[myds.Tables[0].Rows.Count];
    foreach(DataRow arow in myds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        dts[i] = new Results();
        dts[i].Ticker = arow["Ticker"];
        dts[i].BuyDate = arow["BuyDate"];
        dts[1].Buy = arow["Buy"];
        dts[i].SellDate = arow["SellDate"];
        dts[i].Sell = arow["Sell"];
        dts[i].Profit = arow["Profit"];
        dts[i].Period = arow["Period"];
        i+=1;
    }
    return dts;
     }    
   }
```

The VB.NET WEBSERVICE that runs fine which I am trying to convert to C# is here.

```
 Imports System.Web
 Imports System.Web.Services
 Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
 Imports System.Data
 Imports System.Data.SqlClient
 <WebService(Namespace:="http://localhost:2597/Results/ResultsVT.aspx")> _
 <WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
 <Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
 Public Class VTResults
     Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService
     Public Class Results
         Public Ticker As String
         Public BuyDate As String
         Public Buy As Decimal
         Public SellDate As String
         Public Sell As Decimal
         Public Profit As String
         Public Period As Decimal
     End Class
     <WebMethod()> _
     Public Function GetResults() As Results()
         Try
             Dim conn As String =  
 ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("LocalSqlServer").ConnectionString
             Dim myconn = New SqlConnection(conn)
             Dim mycomm As New SqlCommand
             Dim myda As New SqlDataAdapter
             Dim myds As New DataSet

             mycomm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
             mycomm.Connection = myconn
             mycomm.CommandText = "dbo.Results"

             myconn.Open()
             myda.SelectCommand = mycomm
             myda.Fill(myds)
             myconn.Close()
             myconn.Dispose()

             Dim i As Integer
             i = 0

             Dim dts As Results() = New Results(myds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1) {}
             Dim aRow As DataRow

             For Each aRow In myds.Tables(0).Rows
                 dts(i) = New Results
                 dts(i).Ticker = aRow("Ticker")
                 dts(i).BuyDate = aRow("BuyDate")
                 dts(i).Buy = aRow("Buy")
                 dts(i).SellDate = aRow("SellDate")
                 dts(i).Sell = aRow("Sell")
                 dts(i).Profit = aRow("Profit")
                 dts(i).Period = aRow("Period")
                 i += 1
             Next
             Return dts

         Catch ex As DataException
             Throw ex
         End Try
     End Function

 End Class
```

Comment: You should also put the SqlConnection, SqlCommand and SqlDataAdapter into `using` blocks so they'll be Disposed if an exception is thrown.

Comment: Thanks John I'll work on that when I finish the conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As everyone else already said, you need to make the members of Results public.

Additionally, once you've done that, you'll hit errors with the following lines:

```
    dts[i].Ticker = arow["Ticker"];
    dts[i].BuyDate = arow["BuyDate"];
    dts[1].Buy = arow["Buy"];
    dts[i].SellDate = arow["SellDate"];
    dts[i].Sell = arow["Sell"];
    dts[i].Profit = arow["Profit"];
    dts[i].Period = arow["Period"];
```

The conversions in there work implicitly in VB.NET, but you'll need to do them explicitly in C#

e.g.

```
    dts[i].Ticker = arow["Ticker"].ToString();
```

Comment: Any idea why I get this error on the DataRow arow object?

        Results[] dts = new Results[myds.Tables[0].Rows.Count];
        DataRow arow;
        
        foreach(DataRow arow in myds.Tables[0].Rows)

        {
            dts[i] = new Results();
            dts[i].Ticker = arow["Ticker"].ToString();

Comment: that is unreadable.. anyway I get an error on the arow object .....  I declare it using C# DataRow arow then I use it in this statement 
foreach(DataRow arow in myds.Tables[0].Rows)   this is where the program says "a variable named 'arow' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give it a different meaning.... ??

Comment: I posted a separate question on this topic... 'C# Conversion VB.net Webservice'

Answer (score 1):

The default [access modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) for class members in C# is private. Try changing your fields to public (like you have in your VB code).

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to make it all public as you will hit the same error for each of the other properties.

```
public class Results { 
         public string Ticker; 
         public string BuyDate; 
         public decimal Buy; 
         public string SellDate; 
         public decimal Sell; 
         public string Profit; 
         public decimal Period; 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated the default acess modifier in C# is **private** so you have to make "string Ticker" and the rest of the fields **public**. Furthermore you should probably make it a struct unless you plan to extend it with with methods later on.

```
public class Results
{
    public string Ticker;
    public string BuyDate;
    public decimal Buy;
    public string SellDate;
    public decimal Sell;
    public string Profit;
    public decimal Period;
}
```